# Get a Tkinter Toplevel's Size

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to find the size of a `tk.Toplevel()` window, so I can center it:

```
class HelpWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.width, self.height = screenDim
        self.master = master
        self.helpImage = Image.open("someImage.jpg")
        self.helpPhoto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.helpImage)
        self.helpLabel = tk.Label(self.master, image = self.helpPhoto)
        self.helpLabel.grid(row = 1)
        self.masterSize = self.master.geometry().split('+')[0].split('x')
            # this is just ['1', '1']; not the actual size
        self.xSize, self.ySize = (float(self.width) / float(self.masterSize[0])), (float(self.height) / float(self.masterSize[1]))
            # this creates the offset
        self.xPos, self.yPos = int(self.width/2 - (self.width/(self.xSize*2))), int(self.height/2 - (self.height/(self.ySize*2))) # this should center it
        self.master.geometry("+{posX}+{posY}".format(posX = self.xPos, posY = self.yPos))
```

How can I get the actual size? `self.masterSize = self.master.geometry().split('+')[0].split('x')` is just `['1', '1']`, which is not the size of the window, so it doesn't center the window...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Call  [update()](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.update-method) before retrieving any geometry (`mainloop()` is not started yet)
2. You can use `winfo_width()` and `winfo_height()` instead of parsing `geometry()` output
3. Your code does not consider outer-frame

```
def center(win):
    win.update()
    w_req, h_req = win.winfo_width(), win.winfo_height()
    w_form = win.winfo_rootx() - win.winfo_x()
    w = w_req + w_form*2
    h = h_req + (win.winfo_rooty() - win.winfo_y()) + w_form
    x = (win.winfo_screenwidth() // 2) - (w // 2)
    y = (win.winfo_screenheight() // 2) - (h // 2)
    win.geometry('{0}x{1}+{2}+{3}'.format(w_req, h_req, x, y))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = Entry(window, font="Helvetica 60 bold")
text.place(x=(window.winfo_screenwidth() // 2), y=0, anchor="center")
```